# Image inside list item inside link not clickable in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

### The HTML code:

```
<ul>
    <a href='index.php'> 
        <li>
            <img src='images/icons/home.png' alt='' />
            <p>Home</p>
        </li> 
    </a>
</ul>
```

### The CSS:

```
ul {

    height:100%;

    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    text-align: left;
}

ul li {

    height: 100%;
    width:90px;
    float: left;
}

ul li p {
    margin-top: 4px;
    width: 100%;    
}


ul a li {
    display:block;
}

ul li img {
    margin-top: 8px;
    width: 43px;
    height: 43px;
}
```

(I've left all the properties here except the font stuff)

### The problem:

In Internet Explorer only: the whole link (which is a square block with text and an image inside) functions normally as a link **except for the part where the image is**. In that part when clicked on the link does not work. It does, however, strangely, still, show the link in the status bar when you hover over any part, **including the image**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should provide a larger sample of your HTML, but I can already see that it's invalid:

```
<a href='index.php'> 
    <li>
        ..
    </li> 
</a>
```

- You either have an `a` element as a direct child of a `ul` element which is invalid.
- Or, you don't have a containing `ul` element, which is also invalid.
- It's only valid to use an `li` element inside a `ul` or `ol` element (and a couple of other less common scenarios).

Valid HTML would look like this (assuming HTML5!):

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <img src='images/icons/home.png' alt='' />
            <p>Home</p>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Once you use valid HTML, it should work in IE.

*(But, you didn't specify what version of IE, so I'm just guessing that it will.)*

Comment: Ok, it is all in wrapped in a ul. I didn't know it was invalid to put a `li` in an `a`, Thanks.