# CSS unordered list, applying link to the background image

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, background, html-lists

I've been searching through Stack / Google and have tried a few techniques in order to add a link to the images in this list. Here is the basic html for the jQuery slider:

```
    <div id="slide">        
        <div class="slider">
            <ul class="items">
                <li><img src="images/slider-1.jpg" alt="" /></li>
                <li><img src="images/slider-2.jpg" alt="" /></li>
                <li><img src="images/slider-3.jpg" alt="" /></li>
            </ul>
      </div>
```

And the CSS:

```
      #slide { position:relative; width:948px; height:398px; margin:0 auto; z-index:100; overflow:hidden;border:#c7c7c7 1px solid; border-top:none !important; }
      .slider { width:948px; height:398px; margin:0 auto; position:relative; z-index:2; overflow:visible !important; }
      .items { display:none;}
```

I'm simply trying to add a link to each of the background images. I've tried as much as I can think of, last attempt I went with the following on one of the list items:

```
      <li><a href="http://linkedbg/"><img src="images/slider-1.jpg" alt="" />Linked Background Image</a></li>
```

And the following on the unordered list item:

```
      .items { display:block; text-indent:-9999px;}
```

Still can't make the image a link?

Will keep searching but if anyone can point me in the right direction?

If anyone is interested... here is the template I'm trying to add this link to:

http://www.templatemonster.com/free-templates/free-website-template-restaurant-jquery-slider.php

Comment: Maybe if you add your script after the plugin has been loaded? So it wouldn't overwrite your code?

Comment: can you provide a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)/[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/)/another working example?

Comment: Will do Tim B... give me 5

Comment: this is JSFiddle link? http://jsfiddle.net/mrvijayakumar/qsf3ey4y/. .items class will hide all the child elements due to display: none. Correct the JSFiddle code i given boss.

Comment: Many thanks  Vijayakumar Selvaraj... I've tried this I think, display:block; text-indent:-9999px;  does this .items need a width / height also?

Comment: I can't seem to get the jsfiddle to work?  I've included a link to the template in the original post, this is where I'm trying to add the link, to the slider on the homepage...

Answer (score 0):

I normally do like this below.

1. `display:block` to a tag
2. make a width and height for a tag to fit with each img size
3. in css, `background-image:url();` rather to use img tag in html

i hope my answer can help you:)

Answer (score 0):

The following code works fine:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="http://www.google.de"><img src="anImageA.png" alt="" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.bing.de"><img src="anImageB.png" alt="" /></a></li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

No CSS or Scripts needed to answer your questions. Maybe you had a typo, or some scripts included, which disable your link.

Comment: Sorry Waog... you'd think but that was the first thing I tried?

Comment: Btw: a similar question was also answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5700619/image-inside-list-item-inside-link-not-clickable-in-ie

Comment: @soulofmischief I just tried it out in Chrome... it works fine there. Copy-paste the code and see if it still doesn't work. maybe you had a typo or something like that.

Comment: Or maybe you have some scripts included, which disable your links?

Comment: I think that may be the case Waog, at first I thought it may be because I've converted this site to Joomla and that was causing disabling some scripts.  But I can't seem to get it working even locally, outside of Joomla?  Still think a script may be getting disabled somewhere... will keep trying :-)

Answer (score 0):

Base on my perception on your question is that what you are trying to do is `add image on a link` not `add link on an image`.
Use `list-style-image:url('image path here');` see [this](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_list-style-image.asp)

Or if you really want to use image as a link you can just use pseudo elements `:before` and `:after` and you can use other tags rather than `li` - **i love this one**. See [this](http://css-tricks.com/pseudo-element-roundup/)

Comment: Thanks Alexdn, just to confirm, I am trying to add a link to a 'background' image... I'll figure it... eventually :-)

Comment: Oh I see, I guess it is, because the structure of your html seems to be like that. Well then just use option 2 in my answer which is `pseudo elements`. Hope it will help you :)

Comment: Brilliant article on [tag:pseudo elements] @Alexdn... thanks for sharing!